# Converting remainder of a floating point float/double into an int

Tags: c++, floating-point, int, decimal-point

I have a double (or float) number x:

x = 1234.5678;

Now, the question is, how do break down the number into 2 int's whereas int1 would get the number before the point, and int2 is the number after the point.

The first part is easy, which we can either cast, or take a round or ceiling to get the first part into an int, I am looking for the second part to become int2=5678 without any floating points there.

i.e. to to extend the above example:

```
float x = 1234.5678;
int x1 = (int) x;   // which would return 1234 great.
int x2 = SomeFunction????(x);            // where I need x2 to become = 5678
```

Notice the 5678 should not have any points there.

It would be nice to hear from you.

Thanks
Heider

Comment: x2 = (int)((x - x1) * 10000);

Comment: (Note that negative numbers can be a bit messier.)

Comment: @HotLicks That would not convert all decimals if there are many decimals

Comment: @olevegard - Right.  But you have to define in advance how many decimals you want for this scheme.  You can't return 6 decimals one time and 12 the next.

Comment: Might be more reliable as `long a = (long)(x + 10000); long x1 = a / 10000; long x2 = a % 10000;`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - The OP requested an int.

Comment: The computer stores in x something close to 1234.5677490234375, so should it give 5677490234375? Something even longer?

Comment: @MarcGlisse - Or it stores 1234567890123.45.

Comment: (1) The question is incorrectly specified because it says you have 1234.5678 in a double or float, but this is not possible in the common implementations of double or float. The common implementations use binary-based floating-point and will not store 1234.5678 exactly. (2) Additionally, the common float implementation will does not have enough precision to store 1234.5678 without special efforts; the nearest representable value is closer to 1234.5677. (3) The question is inadequately specified because it does not state how many digits should be returned for numbers such as 3.25 or 7.53125.

Comment: So could a loop be used in conjunction with @HotLicks answer?

multiplier = 10;
x1 = (int)x;
while( ( abs(x)*multipler - abs(x1)) != 0 )
{
    x2 = x*multiplier;
    multiplier *= 10
}

Comment: Even if you have a rare C++ implementation that uses decimal instead of binary arithmetic, how would you distinguish 1.04 from 1.4?

Comment: @EricPostpischil - double carries nearly 16 decimal digits, so 1234.5678 could well be represented to .00001 accuracy.

Comment: @HotLicks: Representing 1234.5678 to .00001 accuracy is not the same as representing 1234.5678. The problem statement must specify what results are expected given the actual inputs, not the wished-for-but-nonexistent inputs. For example, it could specify that the desired result is the four digits that result from rounding the actual input to the nearest number with four decimal digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Hi All, the question is correctly specified, it's very simple, needed a function to split a number (any decimal number) which is regardless of being float or decimal or double_t etc. I have already done this in strings whereas I move it into an STR and then split it into two parts which worked fine, however, what I was looking for is a function in C/C++ (or any C) to see if I could use a "built-in" C type function to see if I could reduce the custom functions that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways of doing it.

The first one uses `std::stringstream`, `std::string` and `std::strtol` and is sorta hacky. It is also not very efficient, but it does the job.

The second one needs to know the number of decimals and uses simple multiplication. NOTE: This method will not do any kind of checking on whether the float you pass in actually has that number of decimals.

None of these methods are particularly elegant, but they worked well for the numbers I tested ( both positive and negative. ) Feel free to comment if you find bugs/errors or if you have suggestions for improvement.

EDIT : As **@dan04** pointed out, this method will return the same value for `0.4` as for `0.04`. If you want do distinguish these, you'd need a second `int` for storing the number of zeros after the decimal point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>

int GetDecimalsUsingString( float number );
int GetDecimals( float number, int num_decimals );

int main() {
    float x = 1234.5678;
    int x1 = (int) x;   // which would return 1234 great.
    float remainder = x - static_cast< float > ( x1 );
    std::cout << "Original : " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Before comma : " << x1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Remainder : " << remainder << std::endl;

    // "Ugly" way using std::stringstream and std::string
    int res_string = GetDecimalsUsingString( remainder );

    // Nicer, but requires that you specify number of decimals
    int res_num_decimals = GetDecimals( remainder, 5 );

    std::cout << "Result using string : " << res_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result using known number of decimals : " << res_num_decimals << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int GetDecimalsUsingString( float number )
{
    // Put number in a stringstream
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;

    // Put content of stringstream into a string
    std::string str = ss.str();

    // Remove the first part of the string ( minus symbol, 0 and decimal point)
    if ( number < 0.0 )
        str = str.substr( 3, str.length() - 1);
    else
        str = str.substr( 2, str.length() - 1);

    // Convert string back to int
    int ret =  std::strtol( str.c_str(), NULL, 10 );

    /// Preserve sign
    if ( number < 0 )
        ret *= -1;

    return ret;
}
int GetDecimals( float number, int num_decimals )
{
    int decimal_multiplier = pow( 10, num_decimals );
    int result = number *  decimal_multiplier;

    return result;
}
```

Output :

```
Original : 1234.57
Before comma : 1234
Remainder : 0.567749
Result using string : 567749
Result using known number of decimals : 56774
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/N4Bifu)

Comment: Just store the second number backwards, so the significant zeros are on the right.;)

Comment: Hi Olevegard, thank you for the answer, much appreciated, I already have this work in place using strings, however, I was looking for any kind of built-in C/C++/XCODE "built-in" functions to see if I could reduce such functions which are considered resource intensive.  I also have another solution (a faster one also) whereas to use pointers to access the contents of the decimal variable and manually decode what's after the decimal (re-inventing the wheel). Again, thanks Ole, I was looking to see if there are any built in functions to do this. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are no built in C/C++ commands to do this, other than the 2 methods of:

1) Using the above to convert into string and then scan back into 2 ints.
2) Accessing the memory contents of the memory variable and then decoding manually.